# Magento landing payment page (RedirectURL)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a Hosted Payment Page from my bank that I redirect the client after checkout using getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl().
But once the credit card information in entered, they need to come back on the shop and validate the payment on Magento side.
The problem is that I have no idea where to make the user land ? Do I create a specific page that will validate the payment details, or do I need to use the Magento page ?

Thank you for your answers.

PS: I use Magento 1.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to make a separate page.  I'd look at the PayPal module for an example.

Comment: I created a controller for that.